# danamically creating controlltabs that can be used

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I'm trying to dynamically create tabcontrols which works fine; the tabs are being created however. Once created I would also like them to become clickable and execute other code, this now posing a problem.

The code I’m using to create a tab is as follows

```
            ' do whatever wtih filename
        Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
        myTabPage.Text = TextBox4.Text
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)

        TabPage1.Hide()
```

Not so nice cause I can now fill my form with as many tabs as I like however none of them can be clicked to execute futher code???

EDIT:

```
    Private Sub TabControl_SelectedIndexchaged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim TabName As String

    TabName = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name

    If TabName.Contains("TabPage") Then
        ' Do something

        MsgBox("new tab created")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean `TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)`?  Not very clear what you expect to happen when you "click" a tab.

Comment: eer yes sorry I did however thats not the solution :)

Comment: I expect to have a msgbox("new tab clicked") to be executed

Comment: So, you created a new TabPage.  Now you have to add controls or a UserControl to it.

Comment: somthing like that see the edit to get an idea of what I want

Comment: you need to hook your new tab(s) up to that event handler...look at the end of the line `Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged` you need that for any new tabs you create.  Look at `AddHandler`.  Also that MsgBox will display when clicked, not created/added

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an event handler for the TabPage click event:

```
Dim myTabPage As New TabPage
myTabPage.Text = TextBox4.Text
AddHandler myTabPage.Click, AddressOf TabPage1_Click
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
```

Which will call this code:

```
Private Sub TabPage1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(sender, TabPage).Text)
End Sub
```

Per your edit, you would have to add the name property:

```
myTabPage.Name = TextBox4.Text
```

And your SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                        Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If TabControl1.SelectedTab IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT Assuming you are talking about the SelectedIndexChanged event, then you have to make sure to set the name property when you create the TabPage.  See the code above it in the example.  If it's still empty, make sure you have a value in TextBox4, since that is where the name is coming from.